# how to pass audio input stream to skype?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, skype, input

Is it possible to pass arbitrary input stream to skype? I have a server where skype is installed(skype 4.3 version). Server has Ubuntu 14.10 distro, xorg and openbox packets installed for X Window management and no audio card, so i cannot use input stream like microphone. From Server side my purpose is to start playing audio file instead of using standard input during a skype call. Is it possible?

Comment: This is what you probably want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257992/how-can-i-use-pulseaudio-virtual-audio-streams-to-play-music-over-skype

Comment: It works on my PC but not in server, because it doesn't have audio card. I think this is the problem but i am still searching a solution for my problem

Comment: As far as I know, it should work irregardless of how many sound cards you have. Either you are not doing it right, or there is some problem with pulseaudio in general. Try troubleshooting procedure (way too long to repost it here): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure   Also try `sudo modprobe snd_aloop` to create a virtual loopback ALSA soundcard (it should show up in pulseaudio). Also check volume and muting in `pavucontrol`

Comment: You might get better answers if you ask your question on either  http://askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com and provide full relevant information, such as: versions of installed skype and pulseaudio packages; any error messages from skype, pulseaudio and syslog; output of `pactl list` command during your attempt to redirect audio from an active skype call; exact commands you already tried and errors they produced if any; what programs' output you are trying to redirect into skype; results of your experiments at home. Adding `pulseaudio` tag to your question may also help.